# Reason for replay in Axon Aggregate

Tags: spring-boot, cqrs, axon

I am new to Axon framework When I am going through it I learnt that previous events will be replayed when aggregate class is loaded. I want to know what is the necessity of replay and its side effects

-

Answer (score 1):

Your events is always your source of truth.

To be able to perform events on top of that aggregate, you (potentially) have a bunch of validations to be done. In order to do that, you need to know the 'current state' of your Aggregate. How to accomplish that? Replaying the events and building the current Aggregate.

You can get way more concepts on [Axon Ref Guide](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/architecture-overview/ddd-cqrs-concepts).
You can also read about [Event Sourcing](https://axoniq.io/resources/concepts)!

I am not sure what you want to know about side-effects and maybe you can expand a bit more on that.

Comment: I agree that I need to know the current state but since events are timestamped and sequenced why don't we just use simple query to retrieve the latest state

Comment: Also one more thought I have is since projections are updated to latest state we could even do an API get call to retrieve the latest state though we have these options why do we need replay?

Comment: Your query side has nothing to do with the 'current state' of your Aggregate. This is what CQRS is about. You can have a lot of different projections based on data of your Aggregate/Events.

Comment: Like Lucas points out here, key is the fact you'd be doing CQRS too, meaning you have distinct models you query and distinct models which handle commands for you business validation. As your Query Models will be updated through events, *always*, it's more sensible to have both models be sourced based on events, *always*. That way, you will have a single source of truth as Lucas puts it.